# How to get clap to process a single argument with multiple values without having to specify the flag multiple times?

Tags: rust, clap

I would like to have a command such that `do_something --list 1 2 3` would result in the field in the struct being set to `[1, 2, 3]`.

The following code works for `do_something --list 1 --list 2 --list 3`:

```rust
use clap::Parser; // 3.2.8

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[clap(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
pub struct Cli {
    #[clap(short, long, value_parser)]
    pub list: Option<Vec<i32>>,
}

fn main() {
    let cli = Cli::parse();
    println!("CLI is {:#?}", cli);
}
```

When I use `--list 1 2 3`, it gives me the error:

> error: Found argument '2' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

I've also tried `--list "1 2 3"` and `--list 1,2,3` but get errors for those as well.

I was also able to get multiple values to work as a positional argument, but not as a `Option` with a flag.

Is `--list 1 2 3` something that clap supports?  I thought this was supported by clap's multiple values.  Is there something missing in my setup/code or my command line input?

Comment: Try adding `use_value_delimiter = true`

Comment: Thank you! -- that did it.  I was able to use either use_value_delimiter=true or value_delimiter=','  for comma separated (--list 1,2,3) , and value_delimter=" " allowed  --list "1 2 3"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for the `use_value_delimiter` setting. Set `use_value_delimiter = true` and set the actual delimiter to use with `value_delimiter = ','`.

Comment: Documenation link -> https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/builder/struct.Arg.html#method.value_delimiter

Answer (score 12):

In clap 4.2.7, `use_value_delimiter` is deprecated, which means the accepted answer no longer works, instead, you should use [`num_args = 1..`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.num_args)

```rust
use clap::Parser; // 4.2.7

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[clap(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
pub struct Cli {
    #[clap(short, long, value_delimiter = ' ', num_args = 1..)]
    pub list: Option<Vec<i32>>,
}

fn main() {
    let cli = Cli::parse();
    println!("CLI is {:#?}", cli);
}
```

```bash
$ cargo b
$ ./target/debug/rust --list 1 2 3
CLI is Cli {
    list: Some(
        [
            1,
            2,
            3,
        ],
    ),
}
```